# Is there an etymological connection between the English “arachnid” and the French “arachides” (meaning peanuts)?

Tags: etymology

What is the etymological connection; between "arachnid" (the English scientific term for insects that include spiders), and "arachides" the French word for peanuts ?  Thank you

Comment: French arachnide (1809, Lamarck), from Ancient Greek ἀράχνη (arákhnē, “spider”).  [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/arachnid#Etymology)

Comment: Spiders are insects like humans are sea squirts: same phylum, different sub-phylum.

Answer (score 4):

Get thee to Greek!

An [arachnid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arachnid) is a spider. This comes from the Greek word *ἀράχνη* (arachne), also a spider.

*Arachides* has an English cousin, *[arachis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arachis)* (confirmed in the Oxford English Dictionary). We see this in the Latin name for the peanut, *arachis hypogaea*. This form comes from Greek *ἄραχος* (arakos), [a kind of legume](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=a%29%2Fraxos&la=greek&can=a%29%2Fraxos0).

The two words are most likely unrelated; any relationship would come from their [Pre-Greek substrate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-Greek_substrate), meaning the languages prior to and inferior in status to Ancient Greek that supplied words to the langauge.